# Sharepoint urls moved to apache server? Iframe on new server resulting in 404

Tags: php, apache, sharepoint, iframe, http-status-code-404

```
    <iframe width="450" height="140" frameborder="1" src="http://domain.com/exevi?VIPROG=wn_user_list&DISPNO=5&DOMAIN=domain.com&LANGUAGE=english&INFO=type1&PAGE=user_news_list1.htm" name="news"></iframe>
```

I have a question about this iframe.
We didn't host the original site, but now they are hosting with us, and the site (intranet stuff) works fine, except for an iframe that pulls in news articles... somehow. If I edit my hosts file to pull content from their old site, the iframe works great, but it will not work on our server (apache).

I tried researching this exevi? pattern in the url, but the only thing google lead me to was a vague idea that this may have something to do with sharepoint urls?

The live and old servers are identical in file structure and content. There is no file begining with exevi anywhere in any directory... Any ideas?

Thanks,
Gtk

Comment: You transplanted a Sharepoint site onto an Apache server? There's no way that's going to work. Sharepoint is joined at the hip to IIS and Microsoft platforms. Even if you're running in Apache on Windows, it doesn't have ANY of the background support that Sharepoint's code requires.

Comment: Its apache on linux, but the rest of the site seems to work fine, intranet login and whatever else the client is using it for, but I can't seem to find where this data originates, would you know where I can find whatever is receiving this exevi arguments on the old server (with sharepoint), so I can at least export their data and rebuild the module?